# Not able to install bootstrap 4 (beta) nuget package to .Net MVC (.Net version 4.6.2)

Tags: nuget, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I am not able to install bootstrap 4(beta) to my MVC project. To be precise popper.js nuget dependency is failing to install. Please let me know any possible way to do it(bower install is still a way but I want to go with nuget)

> Could not install package 'popper.js 1.11.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author

Comment: Finally the issue got resolved with popper.js.1.12.1. So steps to resolve is first install popper.js from nuget then update the bootstrap

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was finally able to get Bootstrap 4-Beta working by doing the following:

1.) Install the popper.js NuGet Package V1.12.3

2.) Install Bootstrap4-beta NuGet Package

3.) Update your `BundleConfig.cs` to include the following: **Note the popper.js path**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scrpts/Bootstrap").Include(
                             /*** Make sure popper.js is pointing to umd ***/
                             "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js", 
                             "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                             ));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/CSS/Bootstrap").Include(
                            "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

For some reason if you try to use the popper.js in the root of the `\Scripts` folder you will receive the error:

```
SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

but the version in the `/Scripts/umd` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the /umd/ tip.  That did it.

Answer (score 5):

You can get around this by manually adding the popper.js package to your packages config.

```
<package id="popper.js" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Then you can go into the nuget package manager and install normally.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work for me. Upon Update-Package -Reinstall I am getting the below error                                                                                           Update-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'popper.js.1.11.0' from source '****\packages'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -Reinstall

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get around this problem by downloading the latest (1.12.3 at the time of writing) popper.js nuget package before updating to bootstrap 4.0.

Then in the bundles.config I added the popper js like this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/popper").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js"));
```

The umd version is the only one that worked for me the others gave an console error of

> Unrecognised Token Export

Just make sure to include the popper js file before the bootstrap one.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/popper")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

I also noticed that this then broke the majority of the auto produced template as it's based on previous versions of bootstrap. The navbar almost completely vanishes. I managed to fix mine by replacing it with the following, but this doesn't include any items in the mobile menu.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">   
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Blog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
            </ul>                
        </div>        
    </div>
```

I know this question has a few good answers but this was the full solution that worked for me so I thought I'd share it in the hope that it spares someone a bit of time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here... I created an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/387

Answer (score 1):

The Popper.js NuGet package has been broken until version 1.12.2.
Bootstrap is still requiring the version 1.11.x, which is, unfortunately, broken.

You should wait for Bootstrap to close this issue:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23622

meanwhile you can follow the suggestion of [Rob Quincey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45819826/2059996).

Answer (score 1):

Before installing the package using NuGet, expand "Options" and change the "Dependency Behavior" to "Highest".  Now when you install the package the latest popper.js will get installed first allowing bootstrap to get installed as well.

This prevented me from having to install popper separately.

Answer (score 0):

Again, not a fix, but similar to the fix by @Alex.

I resolved it by installing them separately using NuGet, so first installing popperjs (just search for popper in the NuGet package manager) then installing Bootstrap 4. It seems to only hit the above error when it needs to download it as a dependency rather than standalone. Very odd.

Comment: This happens because Bootstrap is requiring an older version of Popper.js which provided a broken NuGet package.

Comment: Ahhhh, that explains it, good to hear from the horses mouth so to speak. Good work on popper by the way, great little library.

Answer (score 0):

I was not happy with all the files and folders and typescript-related code and NuGet and debugger messages that came with Popper, so I am using CDNs, like so:

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So far it's all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For uses of ASP.NET Webforms:

I've created a new Project with preinstalled Packages (Bootstrap, Popper, jQuery), updated them to the newest version and did:

1. add to **App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/popper").Include(
             "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js"));
   ```
2. Add to Header (Master Page)

   `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/popper") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")%>
   </asp:PlaceHolder>`