# Could not install package 'popper.js 1.11.0'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am trying to install twitter bootstrap 4 beta in my ASP.NET Web Application through Nuget package manager and I am seeing the following error in Visual Studio 2015.

> Could not install package 'popper.js 1.11.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Has anyone faced this compatibility issue? Let me know your suggestions to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well the error says popper.js 1.11 targets (or means compatible) only with .NET framework 4.5.. and the project you created is probably below 4.5 or higher than 4.5

Comment: check the framework of your project by right clicking on your project in your Solution explorer then on Application tab, check what's the framework of your project

Comment: I don't recommend you changing the framework from here, because it will cause a lot of dependency issues with other packages

Comment: @JCBorlagdan, the earlier version alpha 6 seems to install fine. But, I want the latest beta in my project.

Comment: well if you want the latest beta in your project, that i'm not sure if it's going to happen (especially you mentioned it's beta) since it requires your project to be running on a .NET Framework version 4.5 only...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install bootstrap 4 (beta) nuget package to .Net MVC (.Net version 4.6.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666341/not-able-to-install-bootstrap-4-beta-nuget-package-to-net-mvc-net-version-4)

Answer (score 3):

> Has anyone faced this compatibility issue? Let me know your suggestions to resolve this.

That because the `Popper.js` NuGet package has been broken until version 1.12.2, but Bootstrap is requiring an older version of Popper.js which provided a broken NuGet package:

[image]

For the detail information, you can refer to [Update NuGet Popper.js dependency version](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23622).

To resolve this issue, you should install the `popper.js` first, then install `Bootstrap 4`, some more detail info: [Not able to install bootstrap 4 (beta) nuget package to .Net MVC (.Net version 4.6.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666341/not-able-to-install-bootstrap-4-beta-nuget-package-to-net-mvc-net-version-4).

Comment: This is an exact [copy of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666341/not-able-to-install-bootstrap-4-beta-nuget-package-to-net-mvc-net-version-4/45822912#45822912)